# WPF CLR Type to UIElement

Tags: wpf, uielement

I am trying to solve a complicated problem. I am building a dynamic interface and want to convert any existence of an `ArrayList` into a `TreeView`. I tried value converter but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
 if(current.Value is ArrayList)
 {
     var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof (TreeView));

     factory.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("[" + current.Key + "]"));
     factory.SetBinding(TreeView.DisplayMemberPathProperty, new Binding("[" + current.Key + "][0].Text")); 

     template = new DataTemplate() {VisualTree = factory}; 
 }

 var column = new GridViewColumn
                  {
                      Header = current.Key,
                      CellTemplate = template
                  };

 gridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

The `ArrayList` has items that are `Dictionary<String,Object>` and then the dictionary has items.

Comment: Did you try a DataTemplate with DataType as ArrayList ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to do this declaratively?  You can create a template for your items pretty easily:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ArrayListTemplate">
   <TreeView>
      <TreeView.ItemsSource>
         <Binding Source="[{Binding Key}]"/>
      </TreeView.ItemsSource>
      <TreeView.DisplayMemberPath>
         <Binding Source="[{Binding Key}][0].Text"/>
      </TreeView.DisplayMemberPath>
   </TreeView>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'll confess that I don't know for certain that the bindings defined above will work.  But assuming they do, the only other problem you have is applying this template only to items whose `Value` is an `ArrayList`.  You should be able to write a template selector that does that and assign it to `GridViewColumn.CellTemplateSelector`.

Comment: I was using the above technique but binding was not working. I will post some code in few hours.